# wait for expectation but continue

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, uitest

What is the best way to wait for an expectation to happen, but continue otherwise? I have tried:

```
expectation(for: NSPredicate(format: "exists == true"), evaluatedWith: app.buttons["myButton"], handler: nil)
waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Do other stuff and continue
            }
}
//continue
```

Unfortunatelly, that doesn't work since the test stops if the expectation isn't met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `exists == true`, you can use `waitForExistence` -> which returns a boolean value. Once that boolean value is returned (after your timeout is reached.. or when the element exists) you could use that value to determine whether or not to continue. i.e.

```
let myButtonExists = app.buttons["myButton"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5)
if myButtonExists {
   //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence